# Why numpy.var is O(N) space?

Tags: python, numpy, memory-management, variance, space-complexity

I have an array of ~13GB. I call `numpy.var` on it to compute the variance. However, it allocates another ~13GB to do this. Why does it need O(N) space? Or am I calling `numpy.var` in a wrong way?

```
import numpy as np
# data = ...
print('Variance: ', np.var(data))
```

Comment: perhaps it depends on the dimensions of your array

Comment: The array is 1.2M by 2.8K of `float32`.

Comment: I suggest looking at the docs, https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.var.html and playing with parameters with a smaller array to check what's going on, and if the variance is what you expect

Comment: `var` uses the `sum of squared deviations from mean`.  So temporarily it has calculate `(data-mean(data))**2` before taking the `sum`.  `numpy` often combines several whole-array calculations.  It gains speed by using compiled code for common tasks, not by being parsimonious with memory.

Comment: Never be surprised when NumPy makes giant scratch arrays. The design of NumPy causes giant scratch arrays to be part of the most time-efficient solution to almost anything, even if an explicit loop could be more space-efficient.

Answer (score 3):

NumPy will create an intermediate array to compute `abs(data - data.mean()) ** 2` in order to compute the variance. You can write your own variance function with a loop and make it fast with Numba:

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

@nb.njit(parallel=True)
def var_nb(a, ddof=0):
    n = len(a)
    s = a.sum()
    m = s / (n - ddof)
    v = 0
    for i in nb.prange(n):
        v += abs(a[i] - m) ** 2
    return v / (n - ddof)

np.random.seed(100)
a = np.random.rand(100_000)
print(np.var(a))
# 0.08349747560941487
print(var_nb(a))
# 0.08349747560941487

%timeit np.var(a)
# 143 µs ± 414 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
%timeit var_nb(a)
# 40.2 µs ± 530 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is faster whitout parallelization:

```
import numpy as np


def var(a: np.ndarray, axis: int = 0):
return np.sum(abs(a - (a.sum(axis=axis) / len(a))) ** 2, axis=axis) / len(a)
```