# Calculating variance on a large number of samples in Python

Tags: python, list, numpy, statistics, variance

I'm running a Monte Carlo simulation in python and storing the results of each trial in a list `outcomes[]`. Right now I'm running the sim for 5M trials.

I'm trying to use Numpy to calculate the variance of the list with:

```
print("Var: " + str(np.var(outcomes)))
```

For some reason when I try to calculate the variance of outcomes[] the simulation takes an extremely long time to finish. Normally it'll take 10-30 minutes to run for 5M trials but with the `single np.var(outcomes)`  line I've yet to see it complete (even after 2 hours).

Is there a more efficient way to calculate variance by either using a different function or storing the data in something other than a list?

Comment: Computation of the variance of such a list should take a fraction of a second. Something else is probably the issue. Is it possible that you are executing `np.var(outcomes)` at each iteration of some loop?

Comment: On the following snippet it takes maybe a few seconds to generate a result: `python -c 'import random; import numpy as np; x = random.sample(range(10000000), 5000000); np.var(x)`

Comment: Since `np.var` creates another copy of the list in RAM (according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56210689/why-numpy-var-is-on-space)), are you maybe running out of RAM and moving into disk swap space? That would slow things down by several orders of magnitude.

Comment: It's definitely not nested in the loop - it's the very last line of code after a few other print statements that print once at the end of the simulation when it runs properly. 

I'm on 16GB of RAM so I don't think that's the issue but maybe?

Comment: Could it be how I'm updating outcomes[] in the loop? 

outcomes = outcomes + [bank - lastbank]

Comment: @Fubudis use `outcomes.append(bank - lastbank)` instead.

Comment: This fixed it - thanks @bb1